# Migration of repo from Bitbucket to Gitlab does not allow new commit to be pushed to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have migrated the repository from Bitbucket to GitLab using the below commands:

```
# Create a new repo in GitLab
git clone <bitbucketRepoUrl>
cd <repoName>
git remote add gitlab <gitlabRepoUrl>
git push gitlab develop
```

Now let's say after this I add some files and commit them. The files get pushed to Bitbucket and not GitLab. However, after following the above steps I want any new commit to go to GitLab and NOT Bitbucket.

Can someone help me with the missing part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of commands is most likely not complete. You cannot push the `develop` branch on *gitlab* like this without checking it out first. To reconstruct what happens here, I assume that you first checked out `develop` and then pushed the branch to *gitlab*:

```
$ git checkout develop
Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'origin'.

$ git push gitlab develop
[...]
To <gitlab-repo-url>
 * [new branch]      develop -> develop
```

The reason why it is still pushing to the Bitbucket repository (*origin*) is right there in the output of the Git commands. Your local `develop` branch still tracks the remote branch `develop` from `origin`.

To solve this, either you push with the `-u`/`--set-upstream` flag in the first place:

```
$ git push -u gitlab develop
[...]
To <gitlab-repo-url>
 * [new branch]      develop -> develop
Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'gitlab'.
```

Or you assign another remote tracking branch like this later:

```
$ git branch develop -u gitlab/develop
Branch 'develop' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'gitlab'.
```

---

If you want to do a complete migration of the repository from Bitbucket to GitLab, I suggest that you do this totally separate from your working copy:

```
git clone --mirror <bitbucket-repo-url>
cd bitbucket-repo-name.git
git push --mirror <gitlab-repo-url>
```

After this, the most simple thing to do is to delete the local mirror repository (was only needed temporarily) and make a fresh/clean clone directly from the GitLab repository to work with.